# Game misconduct at the end of the NHL match

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

At the end of the Winnipeg Jets vs the Edmonton Oilers match on March 20th 2021, the Jets captain Nikolaj Elers threw the puck in frustration and got a game misconduct penalty.

Since the game was over at that point, is there any significance to that penalty, besides perhaps fines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effectively, no - the game is over, penalties will not affect the result of the game.

The only slight caveat is that the NHL does enforce automatic suspensions for players with multiple game misconduct penalties; [Rule 23.3](https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/assets/binary/319997074/binary-file/file.pdf):

> In regular League games, any player who incurs a total of three (3) game misconduct penalties in the “General Category” and exclusive of other designated categories, shall be suspended for the next League game of his team. For each subsequent game misconduct penalty, the automatic suspension shall be increased by one game.

so this could conceivably have some influence on matches later in the season.